# How to apply winning strategy in Shape Guessing game using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function adjustScor(isCorrect) {
  debugger;
  if (isCorrect) {
    currentScore++;
  } else if (currentScore > 2) {
    alert("You Win!");
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = currentScore;
}

function checkAnswer(answer) {
  if (answer ==
    randomQuestion.rightAnswer) {
    adjustScore(true);
    questionsShow();
  } else {
    alert('Your Answer Is Wrong! \n Try Again.........! \n Press "Ok" ')
    adjustScore(false);
    questionsShow();
  }
}

function adjustScor(isCorrect) {
  debugger;
  if (isCorrect) {
    currentScore++;
  } else if (currentScore > 2) {
    alert("You Win!");
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = currentScore;
}

function checkAnswer(answer) {
  if (answer ==
    randomQuestion.rightAnswer) {
    adjustScore(true);
    questionsShow();
  } else {
    alert('Your Answer Is Wrong! \n Try Again.........! \n Press "Ok" ')
    adjustScore(false);
    questionsShow();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Make sure to take the [tour] and read how to [ask] in order to get started with this community. Your question has not enough details for us to help you. Please edit your question and describe the issues you are facing.

Comment: Ok i rewrite the question again

Comment: Your problem is in the adjustScor() function. As a correct answer will never give the winning output. To win you have to answer correctly 3times and wrongly one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the adjustScor() function. As a correct answer will never give the winning output. To win you have to answer correctly 3times and wrongly one.
One thing to remove the second condition.

```
function adjustScor(isCorrect) {
  debugger;
  if (isCorrect) {
    currentScore++;
  } 
  if (currentScore >= 3) {
    alert("You Win!");
  }

  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = currentScore;
}

function checkAnswer(answer) {
  if (answer ==
    randomQuestion.rightAnswer) {
    adjustScore(true);
    questionsShow();
  } else {
    alert('Your Answer Is Wrong! \n Try Again.........! \n Press "Ok" ')
    adjustScore(false);
    questionsShow();
  }
}
```